# Not able to delete selected row from a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, itemssource

I am not able to delete the selected row from the `DataGrid`. So far I have written this code which gives me this error.

> Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.

```
DataRowView rowSelected = dataGrid1.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
dataGrid1.Items.Remove(rowSelected);
```

Comment: How to do this can you share piece of code?

Comment: Please help me to resolve my problem.

Comment: User ObservableCollection and bind it in to datagrid

        <DataGrid Name="dgrid" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList ,Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

Answer (score 0):

Delete the row from the datasource and refresh the view if you need to.